# Cannot upload more than 5 attachments with GraphQL mutation

Tags: graphql, nestjs, scalar

I am trying to attach more than 5 files with GraphQL mutation in NestJS API server. It works when the number of attachments is either 5 or less. I cannot find any configuration to increase this limit. Would be great if somebody can help me.